# Configure proxy on Rstudio

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio

How to configure an http proxy in Rstudio ?

I see this :
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-Proxy

Do I just need to copy and paste these lines:
"http_proxy=http://proxy.dom.com/
http_proxy_user=user:passwd " 
with adapted user name and password in the Rcmd_environ file ?

Is there a way to configure the proxy from Rstudio options ?
Thanks

Comment: If you read the article, it is said _"[...] you should add them to the R environment **file**"_

Comment: R environnement file is "Rcmd_environ" file? or do I need to create ".Renviron" file?

Comment: Dear @Felipe, finally could you solve this issue with Rstudio proxy settings and packages downloading? I am experiencing the same problem with my Rstudio and proxy credentials. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262480/rstudio-proxy-configuration-on-windows)

Comment: Dear Nuvalue, no I didnt solve this issue. I will be interested if you have solutions