# RStudio Proxy Configuration on Windows

Tags: r, proxy, settings, rstudio

This question has been asked in: [Configure proxy on Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286965/configure-proxy-on-rstudio). However, it was never resolved.

I am a user of `RStudio 0.99.486` version and `R 3.2.2` version. I have tried 2 ways to configure proxy settings in the office without success after reading several suggestions:

FIRST TRY: 
Type in Rstudio as first line:
    Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://user_name:password@proxy.company_domain.es:8080/")

Go to: 
-Tools, -Global Options, -Packages, and unmark option:

> "Use internet library/proxy for HTTP"

I also unmarked the option: "Use secure download method for HTTP".

Besides, I right-clicked on the `R x64 3.2.2` icon of the desktop and added after 1 space in the "Target" camp:

`http_proxy=http://user_name:password@proxy.company_domain.es:8080/`

It did not work as I received the message:

> Warning in install.packages :   cannot open: HTTP status was '407
>   Proxy Authentication Required'

SECOND TRY:
Create a notepad file with the name:

> .Renviron

Saved it in: `"C:\Users\username\Documents"`.

The file contains inside the following 2 lines:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.company_domain.es/
http_proxy_user=user_name:password
```

When I try installing a package I receive:

> "Warning in install.packages :   unable to connect to
>   'cran.rstudio.com' on port 80. 
>   Unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"

After running code line: `R.home()` My R_HOME route is:

> "C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.2"

I appreciate before-hand for your advice and help.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your question. It helped me to resolve my issue. I had to unmark the option to use the settings from the Internet Explorer and restart.

Maybe your .Renviron does not contain the proxy port, you have to write

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.company_domain.es:8080/
http_proxy_user=user_name:password
```

If you specify

```
http_proxy_user=ask
```

it should prompt you for user name and password - then you know that the file is read

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this when I initially started working behind a proxy. Here's what I believe is to be the solution. Disclaimer, I am working on a Windows 7 Workstation.

Even though when you read through the documentation, R suggests that **.Renviron** and **.Rprofile** should be in **R.home()**, that is not the case for Windows.

By default (I believe), the **R.home()** for Windows is actually the Documents folder for your user. You can check that with

```
path.expand("~/")
```

which defaults to "My Documents" directory.

> Therefore, do place the **.Renviron** file with the content you
>   already have, disable the Internet Explorer option in RStudio, and
>   make sure you place the file in "My Documents."

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I also nearly gave up on this problem until I found this simple solution (R3.3.1):

1. specify the system environment variables (in Windows Advanced System Settings add the variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` and set it to 
   http://user_name:password@proxy.company_domain.es:8080/ with your specific settings)
2. in the R console type

`update.packages(ask='graphics',method="libcurl",checkBuilt=TRUE)`