# Not able to connect to my Google Account using gconnect function of gtrendsR package

Tags: r, google-trends

In order to start working with the newly developed package "gtrendsR" (the version 1.3.1 released by 2015-12-10) which in fact is a package to Perform and Display Google Trends Queries, you should connect to a google account. I have tried it several times to connect to my gmail account just as it is written in the instructions, but I have not been able to connect yet.

```
gconnect("usr@gmail.com", "psw")
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I have no idea how to fix it guys...!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package Co-Maintainer here. We write about this in [README.md](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/blob/master/README.md) and in the [help page](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/blob/master/man/gconnect.Rd).

Maybe you have you two-factor authentication? Maybe you are behind some type of firewall and you need to try out in the open? It "works for me" with a *dedicated account I created for Google Trends*; others use the same trick.

If you file an issue ticket, or better still, read the existing discussion over there, you may get some better help.  Right now your question is unanswerable due to lack of specifics or reproducible results.

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk Eddelbuettel wrote, this might be because you are behind a Firewall. If so, you can either unblock the port that you are using for connecting or alternatively use a Proxy Server (I received the same error as you, until I configured a proxy).

For Information on how to configure Internet Access via Proxy in Rstudio see:

[RStudio Proxy Configuration on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262480/rstudio-proxy-configuration-on-windows)

or

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy

For Setting Proxies in R see: 
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/download.file.html